# Trying to get Multiple time zones in POSIXct function in R

Tags: r, posixct

So basically... This seems like a very easy and quick fix but I can't seem to figure it out! I have a function that will give me the dates of day light savings times for the current year and when they will occur. However, I wanted the function to output two different time zones, "America/New_York" and "Europe/London". I wanted to put this in the definition of **tz** of the function

This is what I have:

```
require("lubridate")

dayLightSavings = function(y = format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"), tz){
    startDate = paste0(y, '-01-01')
    endDate = paste0(y, '-12-31')
    d1 = seq(as.POSIXct(startDate, tz = tz),
        as.POSIXct(endDate, tz = tz), by = 'hour')
    range(d1[lubridate::dst(d1)])
}
```

Comment: Conceptually, you have done the work already. If you run the function with `tz = America/New_York` and then with `tz = "Europe/London"`, you get the "fragments" you want. Thus, you can write a wrapper that calls the function with the first tz and then with the 2nd tz. In this wrapper you then need to tackle how you want the 2 results to be returned, e.g. as a list/dataframe. You can also add additional fields/columns as required.
In a more generic approach, you would loop over a vector of all desired timezones. The "standard" looping functions in R will (typically) return a list.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, we need to loop

```
library(purrr)
map(c("America/New_York", "Europe/London"), ~ dayLightSavings(tz = .x))
```